# What type should the returned scores from an R scoring script?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am attempting to develop an Azure ML experiment that uses R to perform predictions of a continuous response variable. The initial experiment is relatively simple, incorporating only a few experiment items, including "Create R Model", "Train Model" and "Score Model", along with some data input.

I have written a training script and a scoring script, both of which appear to execute without errors when I run the experiment within ML Studio. However, when I examine the scored dataset, the score values are all missing values. So I am concerned that my scoring script could be returning scores incorrectly. Can anyone advise what type I should be returning? Is it meant to be a single column data.frame, or something else?

It is also possible that my scores are not being properly calculated within the scoring script, although I have run the training and scoring scripts within R Studio, which shows the expected results. It would also be helpful if someone could suggest how to perform debugging of my scoring script in some way, so that I could determine whereabouts the code is failing to behave as expected.

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this sample and compare with yours - https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Compare-Sample-5-in-R-vs-Azure-ML-1

Comment: Thank you for pointing me at that experiment. I have concluded that the Scorer script can return a multi-column data frame.

As an aside, it appears to me that your experiment is using what appear to be predefined functions that don't seem to be documented, such as set.binary.classification.scores() and set.true.label(). Is that the case, or have I overlooked something?

Comment: I think you may be right that our documentation might have missed or it may be in article not immediately visible at top level. I am following up on it. Thanks for letting us know

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is do data preprocessing before you do the data input. Clear the missing values and outliers. Use relevant data preprocessing techniques to perform those operations.